# Best way to compare the end of a string, use RIGHT, LIKE or other?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, optimization, string-comparison

I need to compare the end of strings against a list of possible ending in a stored procedure. It will be called a lot and there are around 10-15 candidate endings. At this point a code-only solution is preferable to creating tables dedicated to this. Something that would be like:

```
IF (ENDSWITH(@var, 'foo') OR
    ENDSWITH(@var, 'bar') OR
    ENDSWITH(@var, 'badger') OR
    ENDSWITH(@var, 'snake'))
(
)
```

I'm looking for the best way in terms of speed, but also maintainability. Candidates that I know of are

- RIGHT, my favorite so far but it means I have to hardcode the string length, so can be prone to error. It also means cutting the source string many times.

  ```
  IF ((LEN(@var) >= 3 AND RIGHT(@var, 3) = 'foo')) OR ...
  ```
- LIKE, probably slower, but a bit cleaner

  ```
  IF (@var LIKE '%foo') OR ...
  ```
- CHARINDEX, most probably slower since it searches the whole string
- SUBSTRING, most probably equivalent to RIGHT and much more ugly
- SQLCLR to create my own ENDSWITH, it can be pretty quick

There might be better ways I don't know of. What do you think?

Comment: You have to test !! I did a similar test for VBA and `Like "abc*"` was 6 times faster than Left(), but Right was 'only' 3 times faster than `Like "*abc"`.

Comment: Quick benchmark, 10 million compares took 24s with RIGHT, 33s with CHARINDEX, 41 seconds with LIKE.

Comment: 2m20 with SQLCLR, 3m15 with UDF.

Comment: that's eloquent. Thanks for the results !

Comment: @Djof These seem a little premature. Depending on the nature of the data, like can be excruciatingly worse. For example, `col1 like '%'+col2` will take very long if col2 and col1 are both long and, a lot of characters repeat such that you get a lot of near matches before getting to the end(you get a quadratic runtime). I had a condition checking if a smaller file path was at the end of a larger file path, and reversing the strings and using like increased the speed from 2 minutes to 10 seconds.

Comment: Actually, since we looked into this, we've found reverse to be the fastest too. I'm going to change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to optimize this for SQL might be to store the [REVERSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) string value in another column that is indexed and search the left side of that using either LEFT or LIKE.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe. This is for a patch to the code of a stored proc, and it would be preferable not to add tables at this point. Will update question.

Comment: @Djof: If your just comparing strings as in your example, then I wouldn't sweat which method to use much.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had a where condition that was: `col1 like '%'+col2`. The query took over 2 minutes to run. I changed it to: `REVERSE(col1) like REVERSE(col2)+'%'` and it runs in 10 seconds!

Comment: Agreed, time has proven this to be the best solution.

Answer (score 3):

also, you may use a combination of `RIGHT` and `LENGTH` so that you do not hardcode string length.

Comment: Ended up declaring my endings first, then doing this. So far it's the best solution, even if it's very verbose. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Parsing strings will have an overhead, best suggestion is the LIKE '%foo' OR as an option. Certain indexes will take advanage and do Seeks over Scans.

You'd have to benchmark to see if suitable but would be easily testable.

Check this out regarding LIKE and INDEX http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/jnelson/archive/2007/11/16/108354.aspx

Comment: There's no index seeking for a LIKE clause with a leading wildcard.